# Not being able to go up a directory using simplexml_load_file

Tags: php, simplexml

So I am not exactly sure why my code doesn't work, but here is the error I get:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "../../setting.xml" in /home1/sk8ermid/public_html/MVP/themes/SDS-2013/home.php on line 3
```

Here is the code I use:

```
<?php 

$settings = simplexml_load_file('../../setting.xml');
$site_title = $settings->title;

?>
```

I am trying to go up two directories where the "settings.xml" file is at. Am I am doing this the right way or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$settings = simplexml_load_file(__DIR__ . '/../../setting.xml');
```

Always keep in mine that `.` (the CWD) is the directory of the PHP script at the root of any `include` / `require` tree and only then if your configured `include_path` actually includes `.` (which it does by default though this can be changed in code).

If your `home.php` script is included by another script in a different directory, `.` is relative to that other script.

Using `__DIR__` makes sure you're always starting at the parent directory of the current script.

See http://php.net/manual/language.constants.predefined.php